# Не работает display:none в мозиле

Tags: css

Есть ссылка "Закрыть". При клике на нее видеоролик (тег object) получает значение `display:none`. Работает во всех браузерах, кроме мозилы... Как исправить?

Comment: @vinnie, пожалуйста, опишите проблему более детально.

Comment: Попробуй `{visibility: hidden}` и не помешает добавить `<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />`

Comment: не помогло

Comment: Обновите вопрос (добавьте участок кода который содержит видеоролик и ссылку закрыть). 

Убедитесь что у вас в мозиле есть object, а не embed. 

Оберните видеоролик в div и скрывайте его, а не сам object.